# Can't block YouTube using host file in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, hosts

I followed this steps to block Facebook, Quora and YouTube.

```
sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.old
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

In the host file, I typed :

```
127.0.1.1   www.quora.com
127.0.1.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.1.1   www.facebook.com
```

While **this blocked Quora and Facebook**, it couldn't block YouTube.

Then I changed `127.0.1.1   www.youtube.com` to `127.0.0.1  www.youtube.com`, but it still didn't work. What can I do?

Edit : Doing `ping www.youtube.com` gives a long sequence , which is :

```
64 bytes from sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512 (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512 (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512 (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
......
```

And it goes on. Upon killing it, it shows :

```
--- www.youtube.com ping statistics ---
52 packets transmitted, 52 received, 0% packet loss, time 50999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.036/0.075/0.108/0.023 ms
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the output of `ping www.youtube.com` ? Also, I suggest inserting the domain name in addition to the `www` subdomain, i.e. `127.0.1.1 www.youtube.com youtube.com`.

Comment: @MrShunz check edit. Also `127.0.1.1 www.youtube.com youtube.com` doesn't solve it.

Comment: Looks like `youtube.com` correctly points to `127.0.1.1` (`64 bytes from ... (127.0.1.1) ...`). Have you tried `127.0.1.1 www.youtube.com youtube.com` instead of `127.0.1.1 www.youtube.com`?

Comment: @MrShunz I tried , it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Correct hosts line should look like this:

```
 127.0.0.1  www.youtube.com
```

Then your `ping www.youtube.com` should look like this:

```
64 bytes from sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512 (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512 (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512 (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
```

Explanation: The hosts file does not block the connection, it replaces the destination `www.youtube.com` with your `localhost (sayantani-Aspire-ES1-512)`.

If you want to block the destination then you need to use `iptables` with `-drop -dest` and `IP address`...

By using `hosts` file you get reply not from `youtube.com`, but from your `host` defined in the `hosts` file, which is correct.

With following commands you can drop the packets to a `12.34.56.78` destination (replace it with your target IP address):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 12.34.56.78 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 12.34.56.78 -j DROP
iptables-save
```

But using `iptables` command requires a deeper knowledge of `iptables` and the rules you have on your system now.

Comment: Using 127.0.1.1 is also acceptable - that's local host as well (in essence, 127.0.0.0/8 which includes everything from 127.0.0.1 and 127.255.255.255 is LocalHost)

Comment: @kukulo I already tried `127.0.0.1` and it didn't work as I mentioned. Also elaborate "If you want to block ... " part into what exactly need I write/command and where (in the host file?)

Comment: Also by your explanation, why was quora and facebook successfully blocked?

Comment: Added the rules for iptables. Be careful, this might break your firewall rules. For listing current iptables rules use iptables -L